# Why are both “when” and “once” used in “... when it was once broken”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

> Transporting the stone **when** it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

This sentence is by the English author George Orwell from the world-famous book *Animal Farm*. I am wondering the reason why the adverb *once* has been used as well as the word *when* there? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

I *do* know the adverb *once* at this context means *after*.

Here is the paragraph that the sentence comes from:

> The windmill presented unexpected difficulties. There was a good quarry of limestone on the farm, and plenty of sand and cement had been found in one of the outhouses, so that all the materials for building were at hand. But the problem the animals could not at first solve was how to break up the stone into pieces of suitable size. There seemed no way of doing this except with picks and crowbars, which no animal could use, because no animal could stand on his hind legs. Only after weeks of vain effort did the right idea occur to somebody–namely, to utilise the force of gravity. Huge boulders, far too big to be used as they were, were lying all over the bed of the quarry. The animals lashed ropes round these, and then all together, cows, horses, sheep, any animal that could lay hold of the rope–even the pigs sometimes joined in at critical moments–they dragged them with desperate slowness up the slope to the top of the quarry, where they were toppled over the edge, to shatter to pieces below. Transporting the stone when it was once broken was comparatively simple. The horses carried it off in cart-loads, the sheep dragged single blocks, even Muriel and Benjamin yoked themselves into an old governess-cart and did their share. By late summer a sufficient store of stone had accumulated, and then the building began, under the superintendence of the pigs.

One of the answers here thinks that this sentence is ungrammatical - but the poster isn't sure why. I wonder if it is because it comes from such a famous book. Can anyone give a definitive answer?

***You could see the resource in the following site:***

[*Animal Farm* (1945) by George Orwell.](https://www.marxists.org/subject/art/literature/children/texts/orwell/animal-farm/ch06.htm)

Comment: Looks odd to me. "Once it was broken" makes much more sense.

Comment: Did you check the definitions of "once" before writing "I know the adverb once at this context means after."?

Comment: Thanks for providing the source for the quote. I checked some other online versions of Animal Farm, and they contain the same sentence - so it looks like George Orwell did indeed write it like that.  I stand by my assertion below that the construct is incorrect - at least in modern usage.  It could be that a) an older form of "once" is being used, b) Orwell is playing with language for artistic reasons (as he does in other books) or c) an error on his part, or the part of the printer.

Comment: Another example from literature: “Like all Holmes' reasoning, the thing seemed simplicity itself **when it was once explained.** Dr. Watson, speaking of Sherlock Holmes.” - Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: Indeed interesting - see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+it+was+once%2Conce+it+had+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20it%20was%20once%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20it%20had%20been%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Adverb position is often flexible in English, and usage changes over time anyway. I'm sure Orwell's cited use was perfectly natural nearly 80 years ago, but today we'd almost always say ***once it was** [broken]* and discard the word ***when***, but it's the full Oxford English Dictionary definition **B** (conjunction) - ***When once, if once; as soon as.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am editing this answer since the question has been updated since I answered it 7 years ago, and my answer now doesn't seem correct.  Unfortunately since this is the "accepted answer" I cannot delete it.

That sentence's use of the word "once" is not consistent with modern English, and that is what makes it confusing.  However, others in this thread have found that it may have been a more common usage before the 20th century.

A modern re-wording could be:

> Transporting the stone once it was broken was comparatively simple

or

> Transporting the stone when it was already broken was comparatively simple

or, with a slightly different meaning:

> Transporting the stone when it was broken once was comparatively simple

Comment: What does your last sentence mean? And how it is different from OP's quoted sentence?

Comment: The last sentence means that the stone has only been broken one time - i.e. not smashed up into a lot of pieces, but only in half.

Comment: OP's sentence is also the same. Only difference is that in OP's sentence **once** comes before **broken**. How does that change the meaning, moreover how does it make the sentence incorrect? :O Please explain that!

Answer (score 3):

The use of *when* and *once* in the sentence are as a conjunction and an adverb respectively. Such a use, though correct grammatically, is not common today.

According to The Free Dictionary, *once* as an adverb also means **already, formerly, previously and before**.

I think the *already* as the meaning of the *once* fits well in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

To add a potentially interesting point - a perusal of google books seems to show that 'once' appears to have gained its meaning of 'after' or 'as soon as' only relatively recently, e.g.:

> He left for work once his breakfast was ready.

Prior to 1900's or so though, 'once' only shows up with the literal meaning of "one time", e.g.:

> Once he had to sleep under a bridge, and twice in a dumpster, before he took to the road for better prospects elsewhere.

(edited to clarify statement, in response to comments)

---

Note the [examples in the Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when%20it%20was%20once&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20it%20was%20once%3B%2Cc0) for the particular phrase "when it was once".

While prior to the later 1800's 'once' appears to always have specifically been used to mean " a single time", there are examples of the phrase "when it was once" appearing as an idiom meaning "after it is", like [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=5sYTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA381&dq=%22when%20it%20was%20once%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVqo_Yg6_fAhXDtlkKHT0fBiEQuwUIRTAF#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20was%20once%22&f=false).

Orwell appears to simply have been using an archaic phrase.

Comment: "once" in "Once he was lean" does not mean "a single time". It means, "(for a period of time) in the past"...

Comment: I've changed it for clarity since this is ell, but I think it could be valid, if the speaker views it as a single chunk of time.

Comment: Also in your new example, "once" means "in the past". To mean "one (single) time" the sentence must be proncounced with a very strange intonation, stressing "once". It also makes very little sense to mean "one (single) time" here. It makes sense in the folowing: "Once he slept under a bridge, and twice in a dumpster, in the first three deays of being homeless". Are you a native speaker?

Comment: Or maybe a better example: Q: "How often did you sleep under that bridge?" A: "Just once."

Answer (score 1):

> Transporting the stone **when** it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

Here **once** means **only**. The introduction of **once** emphasis the clause **when it was broken**.

**Reference -**

**From OED**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that the stone *was* broken, and when it was broken it was easy to move, but it's not broken anymore.

Here's another example:

> **When I was once** a young boy I played in the fields behind my father's house.

I *was* a young boy, but I'm not anymore.

Comment: I disagree with that: the sentence doesn't scan correctly for me.

Comment: @brendan I agree with this answer. This interpretation is not impossible. I am upvoting it. But once the context is available, this sentence means something else.

Comment: i disagree. once is used similar to "after" in this sentence.

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence **once** implies that the boulders were only broken **a single time**,which means that the animals divided every boulder into two smaller stone blocks that were easier to carry.

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: It's for an incorrect answer.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, sorry. See my answer for the correct answer.

Comment: I don't see why mine is incorrect and yours is correct,so please elaborate

Comment: Becuase it just is... I cannot prove that to you, if you don't 1) see why your interptretation makes little sense in regeards to functional aspects 2) are not aware of this type of usage of "once", as described in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to chime in for this answer.

> Transporting the stone when it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

Firstly, let's see what meaning will fit in the context:

**Once** functions as adverb or conjunction.

1.As a conjunction, once means ‘**as soon as**’ or ‘**after**’. However, the position of **once** here is more to adverb. Anyway, how about if we force it open into the sentence:

> Transporting the stone when it was **as soon as** broken was comparatively simple.
>   Let's cross this one. It doesn't fit the bill.
>
> Transporting the stone when it was **after** broken was comparatively simple.
>   This one is also incorrect, although logically it makes sense. This will make sense if we reposition 'after' and eliminate 'when'.
>
> Transporting the stone **after** it was broken was comparatively simple. So, let's cross this one as well. Both meanings are incorrect and the position is awkward (not a conjunction - which is used to connect clauses or sentences or words in the same clause).

Secondly, let's try **once** as an adverb:

1.We use once as an **adverb** to mean **‘one single time’**

Example: I’ve only met Jane’s husband **once.** (one time)

> Transporting the stone when it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

This meaning doesn't fit the bill. Let's cross this one (x)

2.We say ***once*** a + singular time expression and **once** every + plural time expression to talk about how often something happens:

> They go for dinner together **once** a month. (one time per month)
>
> I see him **once** every two or three weeks.

~ This usage doesn't fit the bill as well.

3. We also use **once** to mean ‘at a time in the past but not now’. In

   > this meaning, we often use it in mid position (between the subject and
   >   the main verb, or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or
   >   after be as a main verb):

Example:

> The Millers **once** owned a dairy farm. (They no longer own a dairy farm.)
>
> She was **once** a schoolteacher but she hated it. (She is no longer a schoolteacher)

Let's get back to our sentence:

> Transporting the stone when it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

Breaking it down:

Transporting + the stone

Transporting what kind of stone?

> A stone that was **once** broken. = A stone that firstly, **at some time broken in the past**.

The meaning fits the bill.

Let's move on to context.

What do we say about the context? The paragraph is about unexpected difficulties faced by a running windmill.
And next:

> But the problem the animals could not at first solve was **how to break up the stone into pieces of suitable size.**
>   Meaning that it needs to be broken into bits.

Let's get back into the sentence:

> Transporting the stone when it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

You can combine the above meanings for more clarity. The sentence wants to convey that by transporting smaller bitsize of stone, they can solve the problem by using the animal.

So it becomes:

> Transporting the stone **after** it was **once** broken was comparatively simple.

The confusion stems from the usage of 'when', where it's not used in an appropriate way, though it is grammatical. It is more like a **logical error**

> **You can't both at the same time transport the stone and break it in the past.**
>
> So, in conclusion, this is more to **logical error** rather than **grammatical error**.

**[Main Source: Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/once)**

**[Second source: Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/once)**